# Get mac address with telnet in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnet, mac-address

I am trying to get mac addresses from stb. When I run "ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | cut -c39-55" on the command line, I get the right mac addresses.

```
for ip in ip_address:

    tel_con = telnetlib.Telnet(ip, port_number, time_delay)
    tel_con.read_until("login: ")
    tel_con.write(user_name + "\r\n")
    tel_con.read_until("-sh-3.2#")
    tel_con.write("ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | cut -c39-55\r\n")
    mac_addresses.append(tel_con)

    print tel_con
```

However, when I run the command from my python script, the output is in the different format.

```
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02760D50>
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02760DC8>
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02760EB8>
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02760FD0>
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02762120>
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02762238>
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02762350>
<telnetlib.Telnet instance at 0x02762468>
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to read again from that connection? You append the instance of the Telnet class to your list, but not the result of the command that is written into it.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasGilch. Yes, that's right. its working fine now. Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

after:

```
tel_con.write("ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | cut -c39-55\r\n")
```

you need to read output again. try this:

```
for ip in ip_address:

    tel_con = telnetlib.Telnet(ip, port_number, time_delay)
    tel_con.read_until("login: ")
    tel_con.write(user_name + "\r\n")
    tel_con.read_until("-sh-3.2#")
    tel_con.write("ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | cut -c39-55\r\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    output = tel_con.read_very_eager().decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
    mac_addresses.append(output)
    tel_con.close()

    print output
```